# how to handle the foucs change for a dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set the flag 'FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL' for the dialog. So that when dialog is launched I can interact with other elements in the layout.

But when touched outside, I want to recieve the focus change. I couldnt find setFocusable(true) api for dialog or set the focus listeners for dialog.

Can anyone tell me, how to receive when focus comes in / goes out of dialog.?

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

These are the properties I set for the window, in `cstr` of my custom dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same flag for the dialog like as below I used.

```
    Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(CustomKeyboardNotLikeAndroidActivity.this, R.style.PauseDialog);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.keyboard);
    mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
    mDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();
```

It will let you to change the focus. Try this I hope you will have fruitful results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus could help